# Actionscript 3 - adjust the z-index of a textfield?

Tags: actionscript-3

I programmatically created a textfield and I added it to the stage.  I placed the textfield close to a dropdown menu that expands when a user hovers over it.   Whenever I hover over the drop down menu, some options are hidden because the textfield behaves as if it has a CSS z-index greater than the css z-index of the drop down menu.

I do not have access to the code that created the drop down menu.  How do I make it so that my textfield is behind the drop down menu?

**Notes** the reason I can't programmatically access the dropdown is because I don't have access to the code of the main flash object, whcih is hosted by a 3rd party company.  I'm building a plugin.  The remote server looks for plugins on my computer and hooks it in.

**Sample Code**

```
package {
import flash.system.Capabilities;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.utils.Timer;

import com.brightcove.api.APIModules;
import com.brightcove.api.CustomModule;
import com.brightcove.api.components.ComboBox;
import com.brightcove.api.dtos.VideoDTO;
import com.brightcove.api.events.MediaEvent;
import com.brightcove.api.events.BEMLMouseEvent;
import com.brightcove.api.events.PropertyChangeEvent;
import com.brightcove.api.events.ExperienceEvent;
import com.brightcove.api.modules.ExperienceModule;
import com.brightcove.api.modules.VideoPlayerModule;
import com.brightcove.api.modules.SocialModule;




public class CaptionPlugin extends CustomModule {

    private var mVideoPlayer:VideoPlayerModule;
    private var mExperienceModule:ExperienceModule;
    private var mLanguageSelector:ComboBox;
private var mSocialModule:SocialModule;

    override protected function initialize():void {

        // Initialize Brightcove Modules
        mVideoPlayer = player.getModule(APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER) as VideoPlayerModule;
    mSocialModule = player.getModule(APIModules.SOCIAL) as SocialModule;
        mExperienceModule = player.getModule(APIModules.EXPERIENCE) as ExperienceModule;
    st = mExperienceModule.getStage();


        var txtCaptionField:TextField = new TextField();
    txtCaptionField.textColor = 0xFDC10D;
    txtCaptionField.selectable = true;
    st.addChild(txtCaptionField);

        // Init drop down menu for captions 
        if(!mLanguageSelector)
        {
            mLanguageSelector = mExperienceModule.getElementByID("closedCaptionsCombo") as ComboBox;


        }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use swapChildren();

```
swapChildren(dropdown, textfield);
```

This will swap the dropdowns index with that of the textfield

You can also set the index of your text field using

```
setChildIndex(textfield, 0);
```

This will set your textfield to index 0, pushing everything else above it.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#setChildIndex%28%29

Comment: thanks, I added more info to my question to explain why I don't have access to the dropdown.   When I setChildIndex(textfield,1), it appears.  Any other index value causes my textfield to completely disappear.

Comment: You should still have access to the DisplayObject instance of the menu somewhere. Can you post more code?

Comment: ok i added the code i'm working with. You need the brightcove api and libraries in order to make this plugin work.  The brightcove api instantiates the drop down without me doing anything.

Comment: You should be able to swapChildren with mLanguageSelector, assuming thats what you want to target

Comment: I get this error with swapChildren(mLanguageSelector,txtCaptionField) `1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type com.brightcove.api.components:ComboBox to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.`

Comment: you might be abele to use mLanguageSelector as DisplayObject. There has to be some kind of container that holds these objects on your stage. You can also try creating a new container for txtCaptionField and swapping depths with st

Comment: cant you just add the text field code before your `mLanguageSelector`?